# How to import Objective-C cocoapod to Swift using bridging header

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm getting no such module KPClusteringController error when I'm trying to import the kingpin cocoapod into my swift project

https://github.com/itsbonczek/kingpin

my Sandbox-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import <kingpin/KPClusteringController.h>
```

my import statement in the view controller

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import KPClusteringController
```

Comment: Where are you getting the 'no such module' error? Have you tried removing the `import KPClusteringController` line? If it works I can post it as an answer.

Comment: it wasn't reading the bridging header file because it didn't add it to the build settings, now that I have fixed that I get a new error - `could not build module kingpin`

Comment: now that I have fixed the kingpin build error now I get a no such module error on  import KPClusteringController

Comment: Try deleting the `import KPClusteringController` line. If it works, let me know and i can post it as an answer.

Comment: I've changed it to import kingpin and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be one of a few things

1. ensure you are using the project workspace
2. Go to Target Build Settings and ensure the value for Objective-C Bridging Header is a path to your bridging header
3. Ensure Your target build coniguration inherits from your Pods xcconfig

Comment: ok I manually added #2 and it now it gets a better error -  `could not build module kingpin`

Comment: Double click your the area to the right of it and a white popover should appear, type the path to the file here it will be something like YOUR_PROJECT/Supporting Files/Sandbox-Bridging-Header.h

Comment: I dont think you need to import KPClusteringController as it is handled by the bridging header

Comment: if I remove the import it says use of unresolved identifier 'KPClusteringController'

Comment: After cleaning the build folders and derived data? I just checked my projects and ive never had to import a module thats injected by cocoa pods and bridging header. Did you import the bridging header at the target level not the project level?

Comment: I changed the import statement to import kingpin instead of import KPClusteringController and now it works